# Show all combinations using MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following table:

```
Customer, Product, Qty
 A         Red        2
 A         Green      1
 B         Red        1
 B         Green      1
 B         Yellow     5
 C         Green      1 
 D         Green      1
```

I need to show all combination, to have a report like:

```
Red and Green
   A     3
   B     2
Red and Yellow
   B     6
Green and Yellow
   B     6
Only red 
   ...
Only green
   ...
Only yellow
```

In your opinion, is it possible to do in Sql (MySql) ? 
I don't know where to start.. i know only it is called a problem regarding "permutation".

Thanks

Comment: Is this format fixed? May be union can help you here.

Comment: It may be possible somehow, but a programming language would be much better suited to the task. So if you should have the option to use java, c#, c++, or whatever, then use this instead of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, t1.customer,
       (case when t1.product = t2.product then sum(t1.qty) else sum(t1.qty + t2.qty) end)
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.customer = t2.customer and
        t1.product <= t2.product
group by  t1.product, t2.product, t1.customer;
```

The values when the product is the same correspond to one product.

This assumes there are no duplicates in the table of customer and product.  If so, then you'll need to pre-aggregate the tables using subqueries.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf2fb/5) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates it.

Note that the output is as a typical SQL result table with columns and rows.  It is not in the format in the question, which would not be the result of a typical SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL:

```
select if(t1.Product = t2.Product, concat('Only ', t1.Product), concat(t1.Product, ' and ', t2.Product)) as Combo, t1.Customer, sum(t1.Qty + t2.Qty) as Qty
from [table] t1
    inner join [table] t2 on t1.Customer = t2.Customer
where t1.Product <= t2.Product -- to eliminate duplicates
group by t1.Customer, t1.Product, t2.Product;
```